# Maximising value for a given capacity

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that will return the maximum value for a given capacity from a list of items.If two or more items have the same value, find the best possible combination.
Function will be like `function(capacity,item_list)`  and it need to return the max_value.
Example Input:('name', weight, value)

```
item_list = [('item1', 2, 20), ('item2', 3, 20), ('item3', 2, 50), ('item4', 6, 80)]
item_list2 = [('item1', 8, 100), ('item2', 4, 100), ('item3', 4, 100)]
```

Expected output for `function(5,item_list)` for list 1 and `function(10, item_list2)`:

```
70
200
```

I have successful get the expected output for given example.However, I keep failing some hidden input test.
The way I do it is I sort the list in decreasing order of value if the item has same value , the one with less weight will prevail.

```
item_list = [('item4', 6, 80),('item3', 2, 50),('item1', 2, 20),('item2', 3, 20)]
```

My problem here is sometimes the combination of items with less value will be greater than the one with higher value but more weight. I just don't know how to solve this problem.
I really appreciate if anyone can give me some guidance and refer me to some resource to read. I prefer simple code solution because I'm still new to all of this. Thanks!

Comment: just google "knapsack 0/1"

Comment: i have tried but the code is too complicated for me to understand.

Comment: post the code you have tried

Comment: This is the knapsack problem, which is hard. The best approach is to use convex optimization. The `pulp` module is good for this. [Here](https://www.coin-or.org/PuLP/CaseStudies/a_blending_problem.html) is a tutorial for it that solves a similar problem that you should be able to adapt for this. (When the tutorial problem minimizes cost, you maximize item value. When it sets a minimum nutrition, you set a maximum weight.)